# What could cause a button on a UIActionSheet to "miss" on touches?

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiactionsheet

I have a UIActionSheet as follows:

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Cancel New %@? Changes will be lost.", [creator propertyName]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Stay Here" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Discard and Close" otherButtonTitles:@"Save and Close", nil];
[sheet showInView:self.view];
[sheet release];
```

It creates the action sheet, The buttons display, the Destructive button is on top, cancel button is on the bottom, other button (save and close) shows up in the middle,

the top two buttons, (destructive and other) work fine, but the bottom button has a gap, so it is farther down than the other buttons. For some reason though, in order to press the button I need to touch where it would be if there was no gap. Touching the actual button doesn't work.

Sorry if this isn't super clear, has anyone encountered something like this? I don't like to whip out the "I found a bug" card too fast, maybe I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its likely that you're showing the action sheet in a view that is in a tab bar controller.

The action sheet appears above the tab bar, but touches aren't registered in the area that the tab bar occupies.

Try using

```
[sheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```